# list index out of range CSV for twitter

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, twitter, tweets

I'm trying to create a data structure for each tweet and I have troubles with the following code:

```
 with open('tweets.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader('tweets.csv', delimiter=',')
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:

            tweet= dict()
            tweet['ID'] = row[0]
            tweet['Tweet'] = row[1]
            tweet['Tweet cleaned'] = row[2]
            tweet['Ticker'] = row[3]
            tweet['date'] = int(float(row[4]))
            tweet['Return'] = int(float(row[5]))
```

It returns an error on the line **tweet['Tweet'] = row[1]** : list index out of range.

I'm new to python and after googling the solution couldn't really find anything that works. Thank you!

Comment: It means there's a line in your csv file with less than two columns.

Comment: @Aran-Fey  can i account for this in my code somehow? I looked through my CSV file and couldn't find such a line. Thanks!

Comment: You're asking me if you can check whether a list contains more than 1 element? Yes. Yes you can.

Comment: You could also wrap the assignments in your for loop in a try-except block, catching IndexError specifically and print row in case an IndexError shows up. Then you can see which line(s) cause the issue and find ways to work around them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f=open('tweets.csv','r')
reader=csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
l1=list(reader)
for row in l1:
        tweet=dict()
        tweet['id']=row[0]
        tweet['Tweet']=row[1]
        tweet['tweet cleaned']=row[2]
```